# Detect when firefox application loses focus

Tags: firefox-addon

I am developing a Firefox extension that needs to be notified each time the browser loses focus. How can I do this? I tried observing `user-interaction-inactive` but this only fires once for each instance of firefox.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

ill answer assuming the extesion is attach to firefox window ( but either way youll understand how to use my answer )

```
var WindowMediator = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var browserEnumerator = WindowMediator.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
while (browserEnumerator.hasMoreElements()) {
                var browserWin = browserEnumerator.getNext();
                browserWin.addEventListener("blur", func, false);
            }
```

hope it helps

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking the time. I tried a similar technique by listening to the blur event of the Window. The problem there was that the blur event fired in a very sporadic and unpredictable manner. For example, some times the no matter where on the screen the user clicks, the blur event will fire. I have not tried this yet but will it not have the same result?

Comment: hey sorry for the wait... try  reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852056/firefox-extension-window-activate-deactive-event/8974221#comment11303723_8974221) this Q i think it will help you