# Firefox extension: window activate/deactive event

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, firefox-addon

in my Firefox extension I try to handle the event when the browser window is activated or deactivated. Adding the events "activate" and "deactivate" to the window does basically work. But noticed that when I move the window, first "deactivate" (when I start moving) and then "activate" (when I finished moving through releasing the mouse key) occurs. For me, the whole time the window is active.

What is the best / simplest way to the "deactivate"/"activate" event pair when moving the Firefox window? Thanks a lot for any tips!

Christian

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to keep track whether the Firefox window is active or not. And it's working as expected if I switch between windows. I just don't understand why a "deactivate" and an "activate" event is fired each time I move the window.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use this:

```
window.addEventListener("blur",function(){
 //mystuff
 },false);
```

and this:

```
    window.addEventListener("focus",function(){
    //mystuff
    },false);
```

Comment: Hi Liran, thanks for your reply! It seems that - at least for currently for me - blur/focus and deactivate/activate have the same effect. They fire es expected when switching between windows or when minimizing/maximizing Firefox. But still...if I move an already activated Firefox window, it fires first a blur/deactivate event and then a focus/activate event. The same happens when I resize an already active/focused Firefox window. So far I found no way to "ignore" the moving and resizing of the window.

Comment: OK, thats weird... i know that i had problems with "focus" event simuler to what you described, so in the end i used a work around:
i used 3 other events:mousedown,blur,resize.

its a littel more work but it does the trick. hope this helps if 
not, i look 4 some thing else.

Comment: So far, I tried a workaround via checking the coordinates of the window, i.e., if they have changed or not. It didn't worked reliably, since minor mouse movements cause to fire the event(s) but not necessarily to actually move the window. I think I will give it another shot some time. Luckily it's more of a nice-to-have feature. Anyway, thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to user timer-based solution: I don't handle DEACTIVE events at once, but only if there weren't any ACTIVATE events after, say ten, seconds. So only after ten seconds I consider a window as deactivated. Resizing/Moving is typically done in way less than 10 seconds. No the optimal solution, of course, but serves my purpose sufficiently.