# how to detect mouse enter & leave from firefox windows with javascript extension code

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox-addon, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am creating a firefox extension and cannot find a way to receive mouseenter and mouseleave events when the mouse pointer moves from window to window.

First I will explain what the extension is doing to make the exact situation clear, because the details may matter.  When the user wants to learn about a "term" (word, phrase, acronym) in the firefox browser, he moves the mouse pointer to that term and pauses the mouse pointer over that term.

The javascript extension code calls window.open() to display a small, borderless popup window (that looks similar to a tooltip) just above the term.  This "clarify window" explains and describes the term with a single line of text.

If the user wants to clarify a term in this "clarify window", he simply moves and pauses the mouse pointer over that term.  This displays another "clarify window" just above the first "clarify window" with information about this second term.  Obviously the extension javascript code is running in the "clarify windows" in addition to the main firefox browser window.

To make a "clarify window" vanish, the user simply moves the mouse pointer outside that window.

To make this work properly the extension javascript code needs to receive events when the mouse pointer exits one window and enters another.  This is what I have not been able to make work properly.

The extension javascript code calls either of the following pairs of lines:

```
1: window.addEventListener("mouseover", meanings.onmouseover, true);
1: window.addEventListener("mouseout", meanings.onmouseout, true);

2: window.document.documentElement.addEventListener("mouseenter", meanings.onmouseenter, false);
2: window.document.documentElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", meanings.onmouseleave, false);
```

When I enable the first pair of events, too many events seem to be generated, and the event.target, event.currentTarget, event.relatedTarget all seem to be various element nodes in the document, which is not helpful because we only care about moving between windows, not between elements in a page.

When I enable the second pair of lines the general behavior seems better in the sense that excess events within the windows seem to not be generated (only at the outer boundary of the window, which is desired).  When the mouse cursor enters or leaves the main browser window, the appropriate event handler functions are called.  Also, when the mouse pointer enters any popup "clarify window", the appropriate event handler function is invoked.  However, when the mouse pointer leaves any popup "clarify window", no event handler is invoked (regardless of whether the mouse pointer moves into another "clarify window" or the main browser window).

Also, the event.relatedTarget property is always null - it does not contain the window or document the mouse pointer moved into on "mouseenter", or the window or document the mouse pointer moved out of on "mouseleave".

I can't believe how much time I've spent on this, as this has to be a common need or requirement in many applications.  Nonetheless, I'm flailing, trying to find an approach that works.

How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: [my answer maybe help you][1], if i understood  u correctly...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852056/firefox-extension-window-activate-deactive-event/8974221#8974221

Comment: I thought events like focus and activate happened when a window is given keyboard input focus, or when a window is activated by the user clicking the mouse on it.  If so, that doesn't work for my application because the mouse merely moves from window to window and generates mousemove events, but no mousedown event is ever generated (which is what gives keyboard focus or activates a window).  Or do I misunderstand how focus and activation work?  If I do, please tell me!  You know, an event like focus or activate that works without need of a mousedown event would be perfect!  Let me know.

Comment: if im not mistaken ( test it i dont have an environment ) i worked on an add on 2 years ago, any way if this doesnt work for you, maybe you can try capturing mouse move event and saving the newly open window X and Y positioning and by doing that you can tell where the mouse is, here is anther link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Windows

Comment: Yeah, I do that.  In fact, pretty much everything in my extension happens as a result of mousemove events, because every mousemove I clear the existing timeout timer and start a new one.  So when the mouse pauses for 300ms, the timeout handler function is called, and the code creates a "clarify window" just above the term the mouse pointer paused over.  The problem is, every window (the browser, plus all those little "clarify windows") are running a separate instance of my extension, so there's not easy way to coordinate between them (plus, the mouse can move out of all windows in my app).

Comment: ...continued...  After reading the pages at the link you provided, perhaps a solution would involve calling window.openDialog() instead of window.open() as I do now.  The key difference is, window.openDialog lets me pass extra arguments to the newly created window - and one example appears to imply that a callback function can be passed.  What I don't understand about that is... what "context" is the callback function running in, anyway?  The context of the extension in the original window, or the context of the extension in the window created by window.openDialog()?  javascript is STRANGE!!!

Comment: callback function context is the scope where its defined so if you define the function in the opener that is the context.

Comment: Okay.  Let me try to understand this.  When firefox starts up, and javascript code in an extension creates more windows with window.open() or window.openDialog()... those windows are running a complete separate instance of the extension (as they should be).  And for all practical purposes, they appear to be separate processes... BUT... actually in fact they are all executing in a single thread of a single process.  I assume this from the behavior you specify, since I can't see any other configuration that would support calling functions in [what seems to be] an entirely separate process.